# How to check signal unknown pulse width larger than specific value with system verilog assertion

Tags: system-verilog, duration, assertion, system-verilog-assertions

I'm trying to check whether a signal has a unknown pulse larger than specific value with system verilog assertion.

Below is my code. But I'm stucked. 
I have no idea how can I check signal unknown Pulse width.
Please advise me.

**Trial #1** -> If signal unknown pulse is smaller than `SPEC_UNKNOWN`, it catches valid Pulse. So I failed.

```
property unknown_detect;
    realtime start_time;
    realtime end_time;
    @(sig iff ($root.TB.vpwrup && US && ~cnt_x))
        ($isunknown(sig), start_time = $time) |=> (~$isunknown(sig)&&(($time-start_time) <= SPEC_UNKNOWN));
endproperty : unknown_detect

unknown_assert : assert property(unknown_detect)
```

**Trial #2** -> I can't use local variable `diff_x` outside the property. So I failed.

```
property unknown_detect;
    realtime start_time;
    realtime end_time;
    realtime diff_x;
    @(sig iff ($root.TB.vpwrup && US && ~cnt_x))
        ($isunknown(sig), start_time = $time) |=> (~$isunknown(sig), end_time = $time, diff_x = end_time - start_time);
  end

endproperty : unknown_detect
unknown_assert : assert property(unknown_detect)
```

I want to know when the signal goes unknown state for a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

**Concurrent assertions sample value in preponed region for any timestamp. Essentially that means that assertions see previous values for any signal and not the value, which is updated in that timestamp.**

This is key thing, which you need to keep in mind.

So now for your requirement here is what you need - 
"Considering the signal as assertion clock tick, if sampled signal value is valid (not unknown) and next sampled value is unknown, then the time difference should not be higher than your criteria"

Here is the corresponding assertion for that.

```
property unknown_detect;
    realtime start_time;
    @(sig iff ($root.TB.vpwrup && US && ~cnt_x))
        (~$isunknown(sig), start_time = $time) ##1 $isunknown(sig) |-> ($time - start_time) <= SPEC_UNKNOWN;
endproperty : unknown_detect

unknown_assert : assert property(unknown_detect)
```